# XML SelectSingleNode where sibling = 'something'

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Consider the following XML:

```
<SomeRoot>
  <SomeElement>
    <SomeThing>25</SomeThing>
    <SomeOther>Cat</SomeOther>
  </SomeElement>
  <SomeElement>
    <SomeThing>46</SomeThing>
    <SomeOther>Dog</SomeOther>
  </SomeElement>
  <SomeElement>
    <SomeThing>83</SomeThing>
    <SomeOther>Bat</SomeOther>
  </SomeElement>
  <SomethingElse>Unrelated to the SomeElements above</SomethingElse>
</SomeRoot>
```

I want to `select SomeThing where SomeOther = 'Cat'`. The following C# code throws a null reference exception:

```
xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
this.path = path;
// Path is passed elsewhere

Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SomeRoot/SomeElement/SomeThing[../SomeOther='Cat']").InnerText);
```

What is the correct XPath syntax to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the load

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path);
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SomeRoot/SomeElement/SomeThing[../SomeOther='Cat']").InnerText);
```

Comment: You can confirm your XPATH here: http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Comment: Turns out I hadn't changed directory to the correct one when running the program from CMD. It was trying to load ./SomeXML.xml whilst the working directory was wrong. This answer helped me figure this out though... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did and it works;

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(@"<SomeRoot><SomeElement><SomeThing>25</SomeThing><SomeOther>Cat</SomeOther></SomeElement></SomeRoot>");

var x = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/SomeRoot/SomeElement/SomeThing[../SomeOther= 'Cat']").InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped with debugging!

Answer (score 1):

**You can avoid using any reverse axis**:

```
/*/SomeElement[SomeOther='Cat']/SomeThing
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett, You are welcome. In XPath it it considered DRY (or drier) if an XPath expression doesn't contain backward axes, such as `..`, which is an abbreviation for `parent::node()`. Expression where there is navigation upwards and downwords are more difficult to understand (and typically are less efficient to evaluate) than expressions where the navigation is only downwards.